# Python InfiniteTimer Test Code on counting Failed Loop fails

Tags: python, counter, persistent

I am trying to test my IP latency and using the InfiniteTimer
I have just added a failCount global but when I try to increment in the tick() callback function I get an error.

File "C:\Users\ken38\OneDrive\Projects\Python\Pinger\ping_test3.py", line 17, in tick
print("failCount: " + failCount)
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'failCount' referenced before assignment

I assume this could be that the InfiniteTimer is in a separate thread and cannot see the global. Can anyone advise please.

```
from InfiniteTimer import InfiniteTimer
from ping3 import ping, verbose_ping
import os

failCount = 0

def tick():
    clear_screen()
    r = ping('1.1.1.1')  # Returns delay in seconds.
    fin = open("data2.txt", "a")
    if(isinstance(r, (int, float))):
        fin.write("%1.2f, \n" % (r * 1000))
    else:
        fin.write("%s, ping failed\n" % r)
        failCount = failCount + 1
    print("%1.2f" % (r *1000))
    print("failCount: " + failCount)
    fin.close()
# Example Usage
#t = InfiniteTimer(0.5, tick)
#t.start()
print('Kat is testing!')

t = InfiniteTimer(1.0, tick)
t.start()

def clear_screen():
    if os.name == 'nt':  # Windows
        os.system('cls')
    else:  # Linux/Unix
        os.system('clear')
```

I have found a work around but I do not understand why the original code failed. Adding a couple of defs to manage the counter and calling them from the callback tick() seems an oddity.

```
from InfiniteTimer import InfiniteTimer
from ping3 import ping, verbose_ping
import os

failCount = 0

def counterInc():
    failCount = failCount + 1
    return failCount

def getCounter():
    return failCount

def tick():
    failCount = 0
    clear_screen()
    r = ping('1.1.1.1')  # Returns delay in seconds.
    fin = open("data2.txt", "a")
    if(isinstance(r, (int, float))):
        fin.write("%1.2f, \n" % (r * 1000))
        failCount = getCounter()
    else:
        fin.write("%s, ping failed\n" % r)
        #failCount = failCount + 1
        failCount = counterInc()
    print("%1.2f" % (r *1000))
    print("failCount: %d" % failCount)
    fin.close()
# Example Usage
#t = InfiniteTimer(0.5, tick)
#t.start()
print('Kat is testing!')

t = InfiniteTimer(1.0, tick)
t.start()

def clear_screen():
    if os.name == 'nt':  # Windows
        os.system('cls')
    else:  # Linux/Unix
        os.system('clear')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To access GLOBAL VARIABLE, add this, only one time inside function.

```
def tick():
    global failCount

    ...
    
    failCount = failCount + 1
    ...
```

---

Alternative solution, variable as argument

```
def tick(fail_counter):
    ...
    fail_counter += 1
    ...


failCount = 0

#call tick function with variable as argument
t = InfiniteTimer(1.0, tick, [failCount])
```

Comment: Do the same in all functions you use global variable. Or pass argument to functions

Comment: Thanks, it was a brain fart. It is a bit unkind that I ask a question and get down tick over a brainn fart.

Comment: But is not recommended use global variables like this. "Note that using global variables in this way can make your code difficult to reason about and debug beyond a certain scale. Global variables are generally considered bad programming practice and should be avoided where possible."

Comment: It is a quick and dirty piece of code that it seems difficult to do without a global. As I did not need to declare the counter as a global I assumed its scope was intrinsically global. How in this case would you have avoided the global? I have not used python seriously but use it as an analysis tool. Thank you for your guidance on this.

Comment: Pass that variable to tick(failcount) and to the others functions. I will try to edit answer as example